# How to upload to "My Personal Documents"

Tags: document

In Salesforce, editing an app, one option is "Choose the Image Source for the Custom App Logo". When I click the "Insert an Image" button, it pops up a window to add a file from a dropdown "My Personal Documents."

[image]

However, I cannot find where to upload an image to "My Personal Documents" anywhere in the Salesforce documentation. Can someone please point me to where to do this?

I am looking for specific instructions like, "Click the Setup link in the upper right nav, then click the ___ link/button, " etc.

ETA: I have found [this help page](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=content_files_upload.htm&language=en_US), which starts with "On the Libraries tab," and they have lost me right there. Where is the Libraries tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're in Classic, from your Home page, click on the `+` sign all the way to the right of the Menu at the top of the page where your Objects and Apps are are listed to get a list of all Apps. Then click on Documents if it's not already displayed. That will open up a dialogue to give you access to it. You can add that to your customizations.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Was able to upload a custom logo for my app. Best regards and thanks.